# MediaRecorder records calls in low volume

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I'm using `MediaRecorder` to record calls. my problem is that other side's volume is very low, no matter what setting I use.

My `MediaRecorder` initialization seems like:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(_audioSource);
recorder.setOutputFormat(_outputFormat);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(_audioEncoder);
```

I use VOICE_CALL, DEFAULT or MIC for as audio source and combinations of `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat` and `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder respectively`.

I also try different values for:

```
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(_bitRate);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(_samplingRate);
```

Is there any other settings I can use to make other side sound better?

Comment: hey did you got any solution?

Comment: Is there any solution